# Glow on shader seems misplaced

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, shader, opengl-es-2.0

I want to get a gradient circle with a glow in the middle. Using the method used in my code. But something is going wrong. The glowing part in the middle doesn't get exactly centered. The bottom part under the glow is bigger than the top part. Checked the pixels on paint just to be sure It wasn't an optical illusion
See image:

[image]

Why is this happening?

code:

```
   // Author @patriciogv - 2015
   // http://patriciogonzalezvivo.com

   #ifdef GL_ES
   precision mediump float;
   #endif

   #define PI 3.14159265359
   #define TWO_PI 6.28318530718


   uniform vec2 u_resolution;
   uniform vec2 u_mouse;
   uniform float u_time;



   void main(){
       vec2 c = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution.xy;
       c.x *= u_resolution.x/u_resolution.y;
       c.y =  c.y;
       c = vec2(0.5, 0.5) - c;

       float d = smoothstep(0.0, 1.572, 0.336 - length(c.xy));
       float glowsize = 30.712;
       gl_FragColor = vec4(0., .0, d, 1.) * glowsize ;

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do the translation first, so that the origin is in the center of the viewport. After that you have to apply the aspect ratio:

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 vertPos;
varying vec4 vertColor;
uniform vec2 u_resolution;

void main()
{
    vec2 c = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution.xy;
    c = vec2(0.5, 0.5) - c;
    c.x *= u_resolution.x/u_resolution.y;

    float d = smoothstep(0.0, 1.572, 0.336 - length(c.xy));
    float glowsize = 30.712;
    gl_FragColor = vec4( vec3(/*0., .0,*/ d), 1.) * glowsize ;
}
```

Note, if the aspect ratio would be 1/2 and `vec2 c = vec2(0.5,0.5)` (this is the fragment it the center of the viewport), then your result is:

```
c = (0.5, 0.5)

c' = (0.5, 0.5) - c * (1.0/2.0, 1.0) 
c' = (0.25, 0.0)
```

If you first translate and do the multiplication by the aspect ratio after that, then the result is:

```
c = (0.5, 0.5)

c' = [(0.5, 0.5) - c] * (1.0/2.0, 1.0) 
c' = (0.0, 0.0)
```

**Update**:

With the following shader you can see the the result is perfectly centered:

```
uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform vec2 u_mouse;
uniform float u_time;

void main() {
    vec2 c = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution.xy;
    c = vec2(0.5, 0.5) - c;
    c.x *= u_resolution.x/u_resolution.y;

    float d = smoothstep(0.0, 1.572, 0.336 - length(c.xy));
    float glowsize = 30.712;

    float dia = step(abs(abs(c.x)-abs(c.y)),0.005);
    gl_FragColor = vec4( mix( vec3(0.0, 0.0, d) * glowsize, vec3(1.0,1.0,0.0), dia), 1.0);
}
```

Preview:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply!. However the issue still remains the same, the bottom part is bigger

Comment: @RomeoTheWizard Is the viewport all over the canvas and do you draw all over the viewport? I mean, is all painted in red if you do `gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);`?

Comment: Yes all is painted in red

Comment: @RomeoTheWizard, When I copy the code of my answer to [https://thebookofshaders.com/edit.php], then the glowing is perfectly centered

Comment: Still the bottom glowing part seems  bigger than the upper part.